# Vue CLI CSS pre-processor option: dart-sass VS node-sass?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli, node-sass

When creating a new project with CLI (v3.7.0), there is an option to choose between `dart-sass` or `node-sass` compiler.

How do these compare to each other, to be more specific than declared in [Vue docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)?

> A Tip on Sass Performance
>
> Note that when using Dart Sass, synchronous compilation is twice as
> fast as asynchronous compilation by default, due to the overhead of
> asynchronous callbacks. To avoid this overhead, you can use the fibers
> package to call asynchronous importers from the synchronous code path.
> To enable this, simply install fibers as a project dependency:
>
> `npm install -D fibers`
>
> Please also be aware, as it's a native module,
> there may be compatibility issues vary on the OS and build
> environment. In that case, please run `npm uninstall -D fibers` to fix
> the problem.

```sh
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): (Use arrow keys)
❯ Sass/SCSS (with dart-sass)
  Sass/SCSS (with node-sass)
  Less
  Stylus
```

**EDIT 2020/01:** Vue CLI 4.2.2 create new project is still suggesting `dart-sass` as the first option before `node-sass`. Yet it has been established here that `node-sass` is the more performant choice, and [almost nobody uses dart-sass](https://www.npmtrends.com/dart-sass-vs-node-sass) (ccleve's comment).

**EDIT 2020/09:** As Ali Bahrami updated his extensive answer, **`dart-sass` is the preferred choice** as **`node-sass` is being marked as deprecated**.

Too bad `dart-sass` in it's a JS-compiled version has poor performance. However, it's developers are well aware of this, and are working towards greater performance as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2952).

Comment: As of Feb 2020, it appears that no one is using dart-sass: https://www.npmtrends.com/dart-sass-vs-node-sass. 3.5 million downloads per week of node, 16,000 for dart.

Comment: @ccleve That's because the most heavily-used distribution of dart-sass is in the sass package, which currently has 2 million weekly downloads as of May 2020. https://www.npmtrends.com/sass-vs-node-sass

Comment: I'm curious as to why there are two dart-sass implementations on npm. [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) is currently the latest, at v 1.26.5 while [dart-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass) is at 1.25. Regardless [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) still dwarfs these two combined: https://www.npmtrends.com/sass-vs-node-sass-vs-dart-sass

Comment: Just a little update, sass has overtaken node-sass as of July 2021!

Answer (score 170, accepted):

### Update **09/17/2020**:

As this answer gets up-votes every day, I thought maybe it is worth diving deeper into this topic.

---

Considering [sass-lang website](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass):

> Dart Sass is the primary implementation of Sass, which means it gets
> new features before any other implementation. It's fast, easy to
> install, and it compiles **to pure JavaScript** which makes it easy to
> integrate into modern web development workflows.

Dart-Sass is fast, but not the **JS compiled version**. Practically when we say Dart-Sass there are two options:

- Dart-Sass on Dart-VM
- Dart-Sass on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass) which is pure JS compiled version

I compiled Bootstrap 4 Sass file to CSS with Node-Sass, Dart-Sass and Dart-Sass(JS) and you can see the following result:

[image: Node-Sass and Dart-Sass comparison - source: https://itnext.io/the-css-preprocessor-dilemma-node-sass-or-dart-sass-32a0a096572?source=friends_link&sk=3c465b78a0e1bc98379afd818546fcf4]

- In this particular case, two seconds is not a big deal; but consider Dart-Sass(JS) is nine times slower than Dart-Sass(Dart VM) and three times slower than node-sass.
- I had a project with +20 themes, it took 30 seconds with node-sass,
  but I tried to use Dart-Sass(JS), and it took a century!
- Although Dart-Sass(Dart VM) is the fastest but installing or integrating it is a bit tricky.
- **And Node-Sass [is considered deprecated](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2952).**

I [blogged](https://itnext.io/the-css-preprocessor-dilemma-node-sass-or-dart-sass-32a0a096572?source=friends_link&sk=3c465b78a0e1bc98379afd818546fcf4) about it here, you can read more about it here.

Comment: At the last line, do you mean `dart-sass` is faster??

Comment: What is the difference between ```Dart-Sass on Dart-VM``` and Dart-Sass NPM?

Comment: @AnandShiva They are the same, one of them is written in dart lang and it runs on dart runtime, but dart sass npm is compiled to javascript.

Answer (score 31):

**24/01/2021**

As it's written in official
[node-sass github doc](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-sass), node-sass is **deprecated**.

> **Warning**: LibSass and **Node Sass** are **deprecated**. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto **Dart Sass**.

So I guess it would be better to chose dart sass if you plan long term or to stay up to date.

Answer (score 16):

node-sass may be faster than dart-sass, but as of writing this dart-sass is the only library which implements the `@use` rule, which is strongly recommended over `@import`. According to the official [sass-lang website](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

> What’s Wrong With `@import`?
> The `@import` rule has a number of serious issues:
>
> - `@import` makes all variables, mixins, and functions globally accessible. This makes it very difficult for people (or tools) to tell where anything is defined.
> - Because everything’s global, libraries must prefix to all their members to avoid naming collisions.
> - `@extend` rules are also global, which makes it difficult to predict which style rules will be extended.
> - Each stylesheet is executed and its CSS emitted every time it’s `@import`ed, which increases compilation time and produces bloated output.
> - There was no way to define private members or placeholder selectors that were inaccessible to downstream stylesheets.
>
> The new module system and the `@use` rule address all these problems.

Additionally, `@import` will be [gradually phased out](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/master/accepted/module-system.md#timeline) over the next few years, and eventually removed from the language entirely.

In order to stay up-to-date with the best practices in Sass, you should use dart-sass (i.e. [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)) for now.

Comment: Very interesting @rasnauf, thanks a lot for pointing this out! With some projects that are importing big libraries' .scss files, it has been painstakingly slow to make even a tiny change to an .scss file and having to wait that all files get rebuilt... For what I've read about `@use` at this point, it seems this could dramatically improve rebuild times with incremental builds while doing dev :)