# What Is The Dıfference Between npm node-sass and npm sass

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-modules, node-sass

I've just learn I should use `@use` instead of `@import` in `sass`. But as I understood, I should use `npm sass` instead of `npm node-sass` to do that. What is the difference between these two ? Why `@use` and `@forward` doesn't work on `node-sass`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Popularity

Blue line is `node-sass`, orange is `sass` popularity.

[image]

The [`sass` readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) explains some of the differences:

> - Dart Sass, from which this package is compiled, can be used either as a stand-alone executable or as a Dart library. Running Dart Sass on the Dart VM is substantially faster than running the pure JavaScript version, so this may be appropriate for performance-sensitive applications. The Dart API is also (currently) more user-friendly than the JavaScript API. See the Dart Sass README for details on how to use it.
> - Node Sass, which is a wrapper around LibSass, the C++ implementation of Sass. Node Sass supports the same API as this package and is also faster (although it's usually a little slower than Dart Sass). However, it requires a native library which may be difficult to install, and it's generally slower to add features and fix bugs.

## Performance

There are performance differences which are covered in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150402/vue-cli-css-pre-processor-option-dart-sass-vs-node-sass/56422541#56422541), which compares the differences compiling Bootstrap 4:

[image]

> In this particular case, two seconds is not a big deal; but consider Dart-Sass(JS) is nine times slower than Dart-Sass(Dart VM) and three times slower than node-sass.

This [article](https://itnext.io/the-css-preprocessor-dilemma-node-sass-or-dart-sass-32a0a096572) has more details about this benchmark.

## Maintenance

`node-sass` is considered [deprecated](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2952), but you can see [frequent updates](https://npmcompare.com/compare/node-sass,sass) are happening for both packages.

**Why @use and @forward doesn't work on node-sass**

Because `node-sass` uses LibSass which is implemented in C and does not receive updates as frequently as the Dart implementation.

Comment: Very minor, but the linked GitHub issue you mention says it's 'deprecated' not 'depreciated'.